# popstate event doesn't animate the scroll

Tags: javascript, html, html5-history

The website I am building has a very weird behavior. I want to be able to scroll animate to the previous section when user clicks back/forward button. Here is my code:

```
var scrollToSection = function($section) {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $section.offset().top
    }, 700, 'easeInOutExpo');
}

$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    scrollToSection($(location.hash));
});
```

This just straight up jumps to the section without animating the scroll. What am I doing wrong?

Full Code: http://codepen.io/Gasimzada/pen/FHzsG. If you open the output frame in a new tab you can see the weird behavior by clicking the back button after scrolling to the bottom or some other place.

Comment: UPDATE: if I click the back button multiple times in a row, it scrolls to some section; but I still don't understand the behavior. Can anyone shed a light on this matter please? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `preventDefault` prevents the native hash jump.

Comment: hmm... I have done that in another website, with the functions. I feel like I am pushing the state in a wrong way or something; I am going to recheck it and will let u know

Comment: Did you figure this out?